# 'Newton-Raphson algorithm failed to converge'

Tags: javascript, node.js, finance, xirr

I am trying to calculate xirr using the node xirr library but I am getting error that

**Error: Newton-Raphson algorithm failed to converge**

```
const xirr = require('xirr');

const cagr = xirr([
  { amount: -99995, when: new Date(2021, 7, 3)},
  { amount: 97642, when: new Date(2021, 7, 9) }
]);

console.log(cagr);
```

[![This is the error ][1]][1]
link is below

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPpt9.png)